# Extracting tuples in a set

Tags: python, set, combinations

I have this sample of set: {(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 3), (1, 4, 2), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3)}.

Now i need to remove the tuples that contains some specific numbers. For example: From this set, remove the tuples that contain [4,5], so the output should be this:  {(1, 3, 3), (2, 2, 3)} for the sample.

I used this code to find all combinations but i'm stucked now.

```
def compositions(k, n):
    if n==0:
        return []
    
    if k == 1:
        return [(n,)]

    comp = []
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for t in compositions(k - 1, n - i):
            if i>0:
                comp.append((i,) + t)
                
           
    return set(comp)
compositions(3, 7)
```

How can i do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a one-liner.

```
your_set = {(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 3), (1, 4, 2), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3)}
your_set = {ele for ele in your_set if all(x not in ele for x in [4, 5])}
print(your_set)
```

Prints:

```
{(2, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def extract(array, filter):
    res = []
    for i in array:
        flag = 1
        for j in filter:
            if j in i:
                flag = 0
                break
        if flag:
            res.append(i)
    return res

print(
    extract(
        [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 3), (1, 4, 2), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3)],
        [4,5]
        )
    )
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).